# EJB: difference between persistent entities and Entity Beans

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I was reading a question about `EJBContext.setRollbackOnly()` method in a mock exam, one of the accepted answers is

> It cannot be used by JPA Entities. [because] Entities do not have EJBContext. Remember that **persistent entities** are not same as **Entity Beans**. Entity Beans do not exist in EJB 3.x.

[API reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/EntityContext.html) states that

> The EntityContext interface provides an instance with access to the container-provided runtime context of an entity bean instance.

and `EntityContext` extends `EJBContext`.

Now, what does it mean that persistent entities are not same as Entity Beans?

Comment: @BalusC uhm... so **persistent entities** are intended as JPA entities, while **Entity Beans** EJB2 (pre-EJB3) beans?

Comment: I believe the Entity Beans in the mock exam refers to the JPA Entity Beans, which don't need the EJBContext / EntityContext, and the reference talks about the Container provided EJB Entity Bean.